# Maven Deploy as tar.gz

Tags: maven

I currently have a jar generated through lein/clojure and a separate shell script. I'd like to use maven to deploy these two as a tarball to a remote repository. Is there any way I can just compress and deploy these two files as tar.gz? I've tried changing the `-Dpackaging=tar.gz` option. Ideally, since I'm deploying artifacts not generated by Maven, I wouldn't have to use a Maven assembly too.

Comment: The term `packaging` in Maven does define artefact's file type (extension) but is not the same thing as `type`. All packaging-s available to Maven are defined either by Maven itself (built-in packaging-s) or by plugins (custom packaging-s), and each packaging brings in certain sequence of build steps (mojos) which result in creation for an artefact file with type defined by packaging. In your case you may deploy an attached artefact using assembly plugin with tar.gz archiving (as suggested by @Mickaël B below).

Comment: Thanks for the detail. Any chance you can repost as an answer? Just want to give some credit

Answer (score 1):

From **[official Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/generate-assembly.html)** :

> ### Cookbook: How To Generate Assembly?
>
> **Summary**
>
> This recipe describes how to generate assembly like zip, tar.gz or
>   tar.bz2.
>
> **Sample Generated Output**
>
> ```
> attach-source-javadoc
> |-- pom.xml
> |-- src\
> `-- target
>     `-- apache-maven-cookbook-1.0-SNAPSHOT-bin
>     `-- apache-maven-cookbook-1.0-SNAPSHOT-bin.tar.bz2
>     `-- apache-maven-cookbook-1.0-SNAPSHOT-bin.tar.gz
>     `-- apache-maven-cookbook-1.0-SNAPSHOT-bin.zip
> ```
>
> ### Recipe
>
> **Configuring Assembly Descriptor**
>
> To generate an assembly, we need to configure an assembly descriptor
>   called bin.xml in the src/assembly directory. Firstly, we specify the
>   wanted formats, i.e.
>
> ```
> <formats>
>   <format>tar.gz</format>
>   <format>tar.bz2</format>
>   <format>zip</format>
> </formats>
> ```

Comment: Like I said, since I'm only using Maven to deploy and not build, I was hoping I could avoid adding assembly. I was hoping for some command line option or quick pom.xml edit

Comment: Project was already built in lein. This is just for versioning